# Automapper - mapping simple list to complex nested type

Tags: c#, linq, nested, automapper

I have a question regarding Automapper,
I have an flat list of objects that i must return in transformed DTO object to frontend, let's say,
List of

```
List<Cars> list =
Cars
{
    public string PartCode { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public string CarCode { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
}
```

and i need to map it to object:

```
public class CarsDTO
{
    public int CarId;
    public string CarCode;
    public List<PartsDTO> CarParts;
}

public class PartDTO
{
    public Part Id;
    public string PartCode;
    public bool Enabled;
}
```

And example data:

```
part_id part_code   car_id  car_code    enabled
1   WINDOW  1   MUSTANG true
2   WHEELS  1   MUSTANG true
3   BUMPER  2   MONDEO  true
4   HOOD    2   MONDEO  false
5   WINDSHIELD  2   MONDEO  true
6   TIRE    3   KA  true
7   STEERING_WHEEL  4   FOCUS   false
8   TRANSMISSION    4   FOCUS   true
```

And proposed output after mapping in json:

```
"parts": [
        {
            "carId": 1,
            "carCode": "MUSTANG",
            "carParts": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "partCode": "WINDOW",
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "partCode": "WHEELS",
                    "enabled": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "carId": 2,
            "carCode": "MONDEO",
            "carParts": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "partCode": "BUMPER",
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "partCode": "HOOD",
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "partCode": "WINDSHIELD",
                    "enabled": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "carId": 3,
            "carCode": "KA",
            "carParts": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "partCode": "TIRE",
                    "enabled": true
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "carId": 4,
            "carCode": "FOCUS",
            "carParts": [
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "partCode": "STEERING_WHEEL",
                    "enabled": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "partCode": "TRANSMISSION",
                    "enabled": true
                ]
        }
        ]
```

Ive managed to map object in Linq with following query:

```
    List<CarParts> carParts = new List<CarParts>();

    List<CarPartsList> list = (from t in carParts
                                 group t by new { t.CarCode, t.CarId }
                                 into grp
                                 select new CarPartsList()
                                 {
                                     GroupCode = grp.Key.CarCode,
                                     GroupId = grp.Key.CarId,
                                     GroupRights = (from
                                                    carPart in carParts
                                                    where userRight.CarCode == grp.Key.CarCode
                                                    select new Part { Id = carPart.PartId, PartCode = carPart.Code, Enabled = carPart.Enabled }).ToList()
                                 }).ToList();
```

But the project im working on requires Automapper to transform DTO objects, and I dont know the solution:/  Ive read the docs at:
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html
But the example in docs is so simple that i cant make use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer here would be to not use AutoMapper, since in this case it will just introduce unnecessary complexity instead of simplifying your code. The [usage guidelines](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/) even state:

> DO NOT use AutoMapper except in cases where the destination type is a
>   flattened subset of properties of the source type

---

However...

If your project *requires* using AutoMapper here, one way would be to define a [Custom Type Converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) that essentially does the same LINQ projection that you would have done otherwise:

```
public class CarPartConverter : ITypeConverter<IEnumerable<Cars>, IEnumerable<CarsDTO>>
{
    public IEnumerable<CarsDTO> Convert(IEnumerable<Cars> source, IEnumerable<CarsDTO> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source
            .GroupBy(c => new {c.CarCode, c.CarId})
            .Select(g => new CarsDTO
            {
                CarCode = g.Key.CarCode,
                CarId = g.Key.CarId,
                CarParts = g.Select(v => new PartsDTO
                {
                    Id = v.PartId,
                    PartCode = v.PartCode,
                    Enabled = v.Enabled
                }).ToList()
            });
    }
}
```

Here's a complete example using that converter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Cars>, IEnumerable<CarsDTO>>().ConvertUsing<CarPartConverter>();
    }).CreateMapper();

    List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>
    {
        new Cars {PartId = 1, PartCode = "WINDOW", CarId = 1, CarCode = "MUSTANG", Enabled = true},
        new Cars {PartId = 2, PartCode = "WHEELS", CarId = 1, CarCode = "MUSTANG", Enabled = true},
        new Cars {PartId = 3, PartCode = "BUMPER", CarId = 2, CarCode = "MONDEO", Enabled = true}
    };

    IEnumerable<CarsDTO> dtos = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CarsDTO>>(cars);

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtos, Formatting.Indented));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Which gives the following results:

[image]

Comment: great, that was my thought as well: don't use automapper, especially since user2829330 already had a working solution.